# get Id by clicking on flash object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

hi all i have flash button in my project what i want when i click this button it should get the id from it`s parent anchor tag

**here is the screenshot**

[image]

as you can see in the image the id is **"coupon-link-18"** which is creating dynamically and further on like coupon-link-19, 20, 21 etc..

The Flash Object is created by the plunging which copy the text into clipboard

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[pw-clippy caption="'. $button_text . '" js="Clickfuntion()"]'. $button_text . '[/pw-clippy]' ) ?>
```

and Flash object is accepting the parameter for a function and the function name is **"ClickFunction"**

so i create the function like so

```
function Clickfuntion() {

                            alert("do something");
                        }
```

Now when i click on Flash object the alert popup will appear. what i really need is to get the parent id of anchor tag by clicking on flash button, the id is generating dynamically

Comment: coupon-link-18 is not the `id` of the flash object . Rather it is the id of it's parent sibling

Comment: no the id which i want to get from anchor tag is not a parent of flash object. it`s one level upper from flash object

Comment: yes there is no id of flash object but there is a function called ClickFunction which perform the action of flash object

Comment: okay ..so you need to get the `id` <b>coupon-link-18</b> when you click the flash object . Right ? And this will be the only heirarchy for all other dynamically created elements ?

Comment: Can you please tell what is the parameter `flash object` is accepting for the `function` ?

Comment: Don't know whether it will work for Flash, but for usual elements you can code from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qw0L4bb/).

Comment: @TusharRaj i was quite busy.. sorry for this.. the parameter of button is js="ClickFunction"

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this

```
function ClickFunction(e){
    alert($(e.target).closest('.coupen-code-link').attr('id'));
}
```

I have not tested it, but you can try :)

Comment: Then it should be `$(e.target).closest('.coupen-code-link').prev().attr('id')`.

Comment: Thanks @Regent for your reply. the function should not accept the parameter because plunging is not allow parametrized function. any other way please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a `ClickFunction`, why don't you try like this :-

```
 $('object').on('click',function(){
         $(this).closest('a').siblings('a').attr('id');

 });
```

Comment: `.siblings('a')` will work incorrect if there are a lot of `<a>`.

Comment: I asked him about the HTML structure . You can see my comments . He didn't replied .

Comment: because this flash button is created by plunging that`s why i cant use which you suggest.. it`s not working